# How to record Piano?

Tags: ios, streaming, audio-streaming, icecast, piano

I have a piano app with touch based tones and now i want to put a recording feature in it. Can anyone guide me to do this. But i need to record this and send to a stream.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [keyboardView setVisibleKeyRange: NSMakeRange(48, 5)];

    if (audio == nil) {
        [self setAudio:[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0]];
    }

    [drawingView setShowOutsideLedger:YES];

    NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"keyboardLayout" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray* names = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    // Load Audio
    for (int i = 0; i < [names count]; i++) {
        SystemSoundID soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:names[i] ofType:@"aif"]], &soundID);  
        NSNumber* audioId = @(soundID);
        [audio addObject:audioId];
    }

    [[self keyboardView] setDelegate:self];
    [[self octaveSelectionView] setDelegate:self];

     }

- (void) keysPressed:(NSSet *)keys {
    NSLog(@"keysPressed=%d", [keys count]);

    [drawingView addNotes:keys];

    for (NSNumber* keyIndex in keys) {
        if ([audio count] > [keyIndex intValue]) {
            SystemSoundID soundID = [audio[[keyIndex intValue]] unsignedLongValue];
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

just give an idea how about you save the key hit note and record the timer for delay on local db. after that using AVAsset to combine the hit audio and mute audio to save or replay back. may it help

Comment: In this case I wouldnt be able to record multiple plays. If the user plays two tones simultaneously only one of the tone would be recorded.